# Which API decides if the call is going through VoLTE or VoWiFi in Android?

Tags: android, xposed, xposed-framework

I want to write an xposed module where I can redirect VoLTE calls through VoWiFi. I want to know which method decides if the call is going through VoLTE or VoWifi and I would hook that method and get the work done.

Basically using WiFi I want to give the network an illusion that the device is using mobile data and send calls through wifi

Note : I am new to android programming. Excuse me if my question looks vague.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to give illusion that you are connected to WIFI even though you are on mobile data.

the way we check that is this:

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
```

So what you can do is, hook getType method of ConnectivityManager and in afterhook method always return ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI

the way to do that is by calling

```
 param.setResult(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);//may be you need casting here
```

in afterHook.

read more about connectivity here:
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Edit: I hope you are familiar with afterHook and beforeHook methods and how xposed works.